# Jquery .load need page refresh but but also return false - help

Tags: jquery, load, page-refresh

Hi folks this is prob quiet simple but not sure how to do it.

I am loading pages into a div a simple like this:

```
$('.pageLink').click(function() {
var pagetoload = ($(this).attr('href').substring(5));
$('#adminArea').load(pagetoload+'.php');
return false;
});
```

That works no probs at all.  Only thing is that I am using CKEditor on "several"of the loaded pages and to display CKEditor in all the pages it seems to require a page refresh  I know this is **TOTALLY wrong and does not work (obviously)** but it gives you an idea of what is needed, just how do you achieve it - if it is possible.

```
$('.pageLink').click(function() {
var pagetoload = ($(this).attr('href').substring(5));
return true;
$('#adminArea').load(pagetoload+'.php');
return false;
});
```

any ideas? - thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Reigel - Not the only one! :)

Comment: It seems that CK editor needs to have a "clear" page - which I assume really means a clear/new DOM

Comment: Essentially what it seems to need is a page refresh before it will load properly on different pages, but I really want yo use .load(); rather than use a <a href=""> link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When implementing CKE you have to use a code segment like below.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

While you are accessing from Ajax this is called before the editor is attached to the page. You can try one thing. After loading your ajax content, then call the CKEDITOR.replace() function on a specified control again. This might solve your problem.

[EDIT]

```
$('#adminArea').load(pagetoload+'.php');
CKEDITOR.replace( 'EDITOR' );
```

[EDIT 2]

```
$('#adminArea').load(pagetoload+'.php', function() {
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'EDITOR' );
});
```

Comment: Hi Muneer, thanks for this but I am calling CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' ); on each page, could it be I am using the same name/class?

Comment: .load is not synchronous so here you call the .replace before the dynamic content has loaded. He would need to exectue the .replace inside the .load callback.

Comment: Yes russp, as redsqure told, it might work if you call the replace in the callback. I have put a second EDIT. please check that also,

** using same class would not be a problem for this.

Comment: This seems like "long running" question everywhere, sadly all the solutions only every seem to "partly" work Muneer your A is the closest as it does work, BUT only for the first viewing so you can "test" it shows on all the pages, but go back a second time and it doesn't show -  and BTW it is destroy not replace - CKEDITOR.destroy( 'EDITOR' );

Comment: what you mean by go back second time? Viewing Page history to back?